# как передать параметры функции по умолчанию в js

Tags: javascript, функции

```
 function modal(id, first = false){}
```

когда так передаю в Chrome то выдает ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ="

Comment: Ну так дефолтные значения (`first = false`) JS не поддерживает. [Ждём в ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters]  В этой статье есть описание но видимо это только эксперементально запущено и еще не всеми браузерами поддерживается

Comment: Где-то через 1 - 1.5 годика все товарищи подтянутся. @modelfak, руководствуйтесь лучше [мои источником](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) (пункт `default function parameters`). Сводная таблица + данные постоянно обновляются. Скажем так, must have для всех разработчиков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого нет. Пока, надеюсь.
Но можно так:

```js
function sayHi(from, to){
  from = from || 'Я';
  to   = to   || 'тебя';
  
  alert(from + ' приветствует ' + to);
}

sayHi('Дьявол', 'Ёжика'); // Дьявол приветствует Ёжика

sayHi('Бог'); // Бог приветствует тебя

sayHi(); // Я приветствует тебя
```